# Alternative to mediawiki with hierarchy, access control, and better ease-of-use?

Tags: mediawiki

Does anyone know of a FOSS alternative to mediawiki?

Specifically I'm looking for the in-built features of granular access control, a hierarchy of pages users can navigate, and more easy to use than mediawiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there's [**Dokuwiki**](http://www.dokuwiki.org/). It's very nice, and it's my Wiki of choice. It is supposed to provide granular access control; I have never really worked with it, however, and my impression is it's not that great (I can be wrong, though, I've never really examined it).

Building hierarchies of pages is easy though, and showing a navigation structure too, using the [**indexmenu**](http://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:indexmenu) plugin.

I find the setup of a fresh Dokuwiki to be a bit cumbersome at times, but the everyday work is very easy and straightforward. I do not know Mediawiki that well so I can't compare, but if you are looking at Wikis, Dokuwiki is definitely something to look at.

There's also the [**WikiMatrix**](http://www.wikimatrix.org/), a comprehensive comparison of a huge number of Wikis, incidentally built and run by the author of DokuWiki.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and the link to WikiMatrix, very useful. After invesigation I think I'm going with MindTouch, a more userfriendly fork of MediaWiki.